# unstable network

Tags: networking, network-manager

I have installed ubuntu in my laptop for dual boot with windows 10.
There are no problems of the network connection when im using windows 10, but  the network is very unstable when i change to ubuntu.I can only successfully browse any websites for 1-2 minutes for every 5 mins.
Yet, the network manager always show that im connected to the wifi network.Restarting network manager only works for 1-2 minutes before the problem come back. I tried using ethernet and it works fine.Im a newbie to ubuntu so dont know what else i can do.

info about my wireless card:

```
*-network               
description: Wireless interface
product: RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
logical name: wlp2s0
version: 00
serial: b0:c0:90:c3:2b:03
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical  
wireless
configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8821ae driverversion=4.10.0-35-                               
generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.0.100 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes 
wireless=IEEE 802.11
resources: irq:129 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:df200000-df203fff
```

Comment: are you using the same settings for windoze & ubuntu; eg. dhcp or manual for both? and if manual - same ip address for both (and haven't given a non-unique ip to ubuntu due typo etc) ?

Comment: it is dhcp for both